# What's a better way to use df.apply on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

After struggling with a csv file encoding I decided to do the encoding heresy of  manually replacing some characters.

This is how the dataframe looks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : 'bÃ‰d encoded',
               'b' : ['foo', 'bar'] * 3,
               'c' : 'bÃ‰d encoded too'})


              a    b                 c
0  bÃ‰d encoded  foo  bÃ‰d encoded too
1  bÃ‰d encoded  bar  bÃ‰d encoded too
2  bÃ‰d encoded  foo  bÃ‰d encoded too
3  bÃ‰d encoded  bar  bÃ‰d encoded too
4  bÃ‰d encoded  foo  bÃ‰d encoded too
5  bÃ‰d encoded  bar  bÃ‰d encoded too
```

If my only problem was column 'a' this function would be enough:

```
def force_good_e(row):
    col = row['a']
    if 'Ã‰' in col:
        col = col.replace('Ã‰','a') 
    return col

df['a'] = df.apply(force_good_e, axis=1)
```

But then I would need another function for column 'c'

I got an improvement with this:

```
def force_good_es(row, column):
    col = row[column]
    if 'Ã‰' in col:
        col = col.replace('Ã‰','a') 
    return col


df['a'] = df.apply(lambda x: force_good_es(x,'a'), axis=1)
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: force_good_es(x,'c'), axis=1)
```

But it got me wondering, is there a better way to do this?

i.e. eliminating the need to make one line of

```
df[n] = df.apply(lambda x: force_good_es(x,n), axis=1)
```

for each n column that needs to be fixed.

Comment: `df.replace({'Ã‰':'a'},regex=True) 
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str.replace`

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.replace('Ã‰','a')
df['c'] = df['c'].str.replace('Ã‰','a')
```

or like @wen mentioned in comments.

```
df = df.replace({'Ã‰':'a'},regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks Abhi, I think you answered before my editing, but wen's solution works best as it eliminates the 1:1 relation of lines/columns to be changed.

Comment: Yes it replaces over entire `df` but when you only want to replace chars only from certain columns not all columns then you can use `str.replace`. Yw:) Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

In case that character occurs in all columns but you want to replace it only in selected columns, and you want use `apply`:

```
df.iloc[:,[0,2]].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('Ã‰','a'), axis=1)
```

Occurrence of `Ã‰` in first and third columns will be replaced by `a`.